# Puzzled using codeigniter on shared hosting server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

This ones a new on me. I'm transferring a site I made in codeigniter to a godaddy shared hosting server. I can get to the home page with:

```
http://www.example.com
```

But when I try to go to the other pages like:

```
http://www.example.com/about-us/
```

It throws me this error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /example/index.php/about-us/ was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If I use:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/about-us/
```

The page appears as clear as day.

I have looked up CI workaround , but my site is more of static pages then dynamic pages.

Overall, my question is, what am I doing wrong and does this have anything to do with having a godaddy shared hosting account?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**CI Config file**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

**CI autoload file**

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**09-30-2011 Update:**

In the .htaccess use:

```
# Options
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

#Enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On
#the location of the root of your site
#if writing for subdirectories, you would enter /subdirectory
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to CodeIgniter system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css
#folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In the CI config file:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Source:   [codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/133292/P15)

Comment: Don't put "solved" or similar in the title or question.  Please post your solution as an answer below instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an .htaccess issue.  Try changing your .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm.  Try looking at this article (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Godaddy_Installaton_Tips) and the associated discussion (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/133292/).  There are some posts from 2011 that may be helpful.

Comment: Also, try adding `Options +FollowSymLinks` on a new line after `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: If you found it from my links could you upvote or accept my answer?  If you didn't, post the solution here so others can see.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Your updated .htaccess is right. you need a small change in it.
change below line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in your `config.php`

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a godaddy solution, but same error on my WAMP localhost...

I had a simple fix to this, which started to occur after I upgraded my WAMPserver. It had set up a new apache config and it had turned off the rewrite_module.

To fix, I just left click wamperver icon->Apache->Apache Modules->rewrite_module and make sure that is ticked.