# error while uploading codeigniter 3 on godaddy .only the default controller is working

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter version 3. It's working absolutely fine in localhost, but when I am trying to upload this to godaddy server ,only default controller is working. Please anyone suggest the necessary configuration changes. I tried changing the .htaccess file but not working.

Comment: if anyone have successfully uploaded codeignitor version 3 on godaddy or any server pls provide the code .i need it urgently .

Comment: [.htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615284/puzzled-using-codeigniter-on-shared-hosting-server) tweek for godaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working configuration on my godaddy server.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**routes.php**

```
# Default
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**UPDATE:**
1) [base_url()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)
2) [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)
3) [.htaccess](http://htaccess-guide.com/)

Comment: i was making a mistake in naming the controller .now its working .now can anyone please tell me whats the use of base_url ...how it is efficiently used ..and in htaccess you (parag tyagi ) have used robots\.txt   ..can u expalin the efficient use of robots.txt and  please provide link to understand the rules defined in htaccess.  am asking too many questions.but i want to learn all this ..